# google assistant actions without voice input

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I'm trying some home automation where the idea is that motion sensors detect a person in the room and the output from the sensors wakes up a Google Home device which starts talking to the person pro-actively. Is this even possible? Is there any way to trigger Google Assistant without speaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment using the Google Home. If you were to use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview), you can use anything as a trigger for your own hardware.